# How can I remote test a user using dual monitors to perform a task?

Tags: usability-study, sharing

I need to do a remote usability study where users are using two monitors to do a task. I was curious if others have had to do something similar and if so how did you execute on such a study. Specifically being able to observe both of the users screens at once.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a User Experience question; it's a request for tools / products etc. Product recommendation questions are not in scope for this site I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm asking if/how other peers have done remote testing when having to record a user performing a task on dual monitors. How is this not in the realm of User Experience? Is this not the proper place to ask about User Studies?

Comment: @dmasini I think with a rewording the question could work. Perhaps instead of focusing on the tools you focus the question on the methodology/study and a good answer would surely include the "how" which would include tools.

Comment: Ok. Will see if this edit is better.

Comment: I can't imagine any of the remote-testing platforms support this. I hope you get some good alternatives.

Comment: I'm not familiar with specific remote-testing platforms, but you may be able to use Remote Desktop to connect to their computer and observe that way: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session/

Comment: After some research I have found a video conferencing platform that allows me to view both monitor screens as one long side-by-side screen. This is really helpful for me specifically since I need to observe the user using a workstation mimicking the one they use on a daily basis. And I'm across the country from the people I'll be testing.

Comment: I've used Skype for Business (formerly Lync) to share multiple desktops. That works well.